# Can you say "c'est tombé sur quelqu'un" when something unpleasant has happened to you?

Tags: expressions, usage

I usually say "c'est tombé sur quelqu'un" when something fortunate has fallen in your lap, as in:

> Il n’y avait qu’une chance sur mille de gagner, et **c'est tombé sur** ma sœur !

But is it possible to use the phrase when something unpleasant has happened to you, as in:

> On aurait dit que le chef cherchait quelqu'un sur qui passer sa colère. Et hélas, **c'est tombé sur** moi...

Or will this be taken as a ***sarcastic*** remark, making it sound as if you consider a spot of bad luck to be a blessing in disguise when it is actually not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ***c'est tombé sur...*** can be used regardless of whether it is good or bad luck. It is not sarcastic in the latter case.

Comment: I suppose this is an expression reserved for an informal conversation. What would be a moderately formal alternative?

Comment: *Le sort m'a choisi*, *le hasard t'a désigné*, *les dieux lui ont été favorables*, *la chance nous a souri*...